# How to select only a link while web scrapping a HTML which the attribute has also text?

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, hyperlink

As a part of a a bigger webscrapping project, I want to extract the html link from a html. It is not all html link on the page, but only the in the second column of the big table.

An example of how the html these links appear look like:

```
<a href="exibir?proc=18955/989/20&amp;offset=0">18955/989/20</a>
```

I would like to have a list the "exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0" and NOT the "18955/989/20".

So far, i could only get them both together (code bellow). How can I get rid of it? Is there another solution? At the end I would like to have only a list of the links in the order they already appear.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import csv

s = HTMLSession()
def get_product_links(page):
  url = f"https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/pesquisar?txtTdPalvs=munic%C3%ADpio+pessoal+37&txtExp=temporari&txtQqUma=admiss%C3%A3o+contrata%C3%A7%C3%A3o&txtNenhPalvs=&txtNumIni=&txtNumFim=&tipoBuscaTxt=Documento&_tipoBuscaTxt=on&quantTrechos=1&processo=&exercicio=&dataAutuacaoInicio=&dataAutuacaoFim=&dataPubInicio=01%2F01%2F2021&dataPubFim=31%2F12%2F2021&_relator=1&_auditor=1&_materia=1&tipoDocumento=2&_tipoDocumento=1&acao=Executa&offset={page}"
  links = []
  r = s.get(url)
  products = r.html.find('td.small a')
  for item in products:
    links.append(item.find('a', first=True).attrs['href'])
  return links
page1 = get_product_links(0)

print(page1)
```

Comment: This looks to me like a classic [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please clarify: are you looking to extract all links to .PDF documents from that page?

Comment: Hey, thank you! I edit it. I only want to extract the links from the second column of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to get those links from the second column. You're welcome to functionalize it if you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using Jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(0, 410, 10)):
    url = f'https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/pesquisar?txtTdPalvs=munic%C3%ADpio+pessoal+37&txtExp=temporari&txtQqUma=admiss%C3%A3o+contrata%C3%A7%C3%A3o&txtNenhPalvs=&txtNumIni=&txtNumFim=&tipoBuscaTxt=Documento&_tipoBuscaTxt=on&quantTrechos=1&processo=&exercicio=&dataAutuacaoInicio=&dataAutuacaoFim=&dataPubInicio=01%2F01%2F2021&dataPubFim=31%2F12%2F2021&_relator=1&_auditor=1&_materia=1&tipoDocumento=2&_tipoDocumento=1&acao=Executa&offset={x}'
    r = s.get(url)
    urls = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select('tr[class="borda-superior"] td:nth-of-type(2) a')
    big_list.extend([(x.text.strip(), 'https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/' + x.get('href')) for x in urls])
df = pd.DataFrame(big_list, columns = ['title', 'url'])   
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
41/41 [00:30<00:00, 1.42it/s]
title   url
0   18955/989/20    https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0
1   13614/989/18    https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=13614/989/18&offset=0
2   6269/989/19 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=6269/989/19&offset=0
3   14011/989/19    https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=14011/989/19&offset=0
4   14082/989/19    https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=14082/989/19&offset=0
... ... ...
399 4023/989/18 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=4023/989/18&offset=390
400 4024/989/18 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=4024/989/18&offset=400
401 4025/989/18 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=4025/989/18&offset=400
402 4026/989/18 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=4026/989/18&offset=400
403 4027/989/18 https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/exibir?proc=4027/989/18&offset=400
404 rows × 2 columns
```

Edit: If you want only the (partial) url as a list, all you have to do is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm ## if Jupyter: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

big_list = []
for x in tqdm(range(0, 410, 10)):
    url = f'https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/pesquisar?txtTdPalvs=munic%C3%ADpio+pessoal+37&txtExp=temporari&txtQqUma=admiss%C3%A3o+contrata%C3%A7%C3%A3o&txtNenhPalvs=&txtNumIni=&txtNumFim=&tipoBuscaTxt=Documento&_tipoBuscaTxt=on&quantTrechos=1&processo=&exercicio=&dataAutuacaoInicio=&dataAutuacaoFim=&dataPubInicio=01%2F01%2F2021&dataPubFim=31%2F12%2F2021&_relator=1&_auditor=1&_materia=1&tipoDocumento=2&_tipoDocumento=1&acao=Executa&offset={x}'
    r = s.get(url)
    urls = bs(r.text, 'html.parser').select('tr[class="borda-superior"] td:nth-of-type(2) a')
    big_list.extend([x.get('href') for x in urls])
print(big_list)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
41/41 [00:29<00:00, 1.83it/s]
['exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=13614/989/18&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=6269/989/19&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=14011/989/19&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=14082/989/19&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=14238/989/19&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=14141/989/20&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=15371/989/19&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=15388/989/20&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=12911/989/16&offset=0',
 'exibir?proc=1735/002/11&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=23494/989/18&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=24496/989/19&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=17110/989/18&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=24043/989/19&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=2515/989/20&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=1891/989/20&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=15026/989/20&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=9070/989/20&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=21543/989/20&offset=10',
 'exibir?proc=19654/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=19678/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=5714/989/19&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=20493/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=4671/989/19&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=14200/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=15277/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=1363/007/12&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=4908/989/19&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=15164/989/20&offset=20',
 'exibir?proc=4418/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4890/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=17924/989/20&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4742/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=800226/465/09&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=23880/989/20&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4561/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4540/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4471/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4982/989/19&offset=30',
 'exibir?proc=4519/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4632/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4536/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4622/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=14734/989/16&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4678/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=5501/989/16&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=13988/989/17&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4854/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4609/989/19&offset=40',
 'exibir?proc=4717/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4673/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=20988/989/20&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4481/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4675/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4451/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=12943/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=23644/989/18&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=23875/989/18&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4679/989/19&offset=50',
 'exibir?proc=4425/989/19&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=2726/989/18&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=17172/989/20&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=2901/989/18&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=4469/989/19&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=299/012/13&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=4915/989/19&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=22649/989/20&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=22887/989/20&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=4721/989/19&offset=60',
 'exibir?proc=4378/989/19&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=4935/989/19&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=4714/989/19&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=1230/989/21&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=1847/989/21&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=15606/989/21&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=11267/989/18&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=1232/004/12&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=4421/989/19&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=4931/989/19&offset=70',
 'exibir?proc=4885/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=5002/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=21592/989/20&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4839/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4783/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4599/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4702/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4617/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4970/989/16&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=4492/989/19&offset=80',
 'exibir?proc=2582/989/17&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4993/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4658/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4606/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4387/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=14549/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4525/989/18&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4713/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=838/001/14&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=4971/989/19&offset=90',
 'exibir?proc=17505/989/18&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=5096/989/18&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=4413/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=4392/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=15132/989/20&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=4517/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=4760/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=18509/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=4952/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=5013/989/19&offset=100',
 'exibir?proc=12922/989/19&offset=110',
 'exibir?proc=6194/989/16&offset=110',
 'exibir?proc=19323/989/20&offset=110',
 'exibir?proc=4732/989/19&offset=110',
...]
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant "I would like to have a list the "exibir?proc=18955/989/20&offset=0" and not the "18955/989/20"". What would be the simplest way to get a list of these html links?

Comment: There you go @JoãoPedroRodriguesOliveira, I edited my answer. Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you! Barry, what would be the difference if I wanted exclusively the links from the first html page?

Comment: You either limit the range to `for x in tqdm(range(0, 10, 10)):` or skip the for loop  completely, and just scrape the first page: `https://www.tce.sp.gov.br/jurisprudencia/pesquisar?txtTdPalvs=munic%C3%ADpio+pessoal+37&txtExp=temporari&txtQqUma=admiss%C3%A3o+contrata%C3%A7%C3%A3o&txtNenhPalvs=&txtNumIni=&txtNumFim=&tipoBuscaTxt=Documento&_tipoBuscaTxt=on&quantTrechos=1&processo=&exercicio=&dataAutuacaoInicio=&dataAutuacaoFim=&dataPubInicio=01%2F01%2F2021&dataPubFim=31%2F12%2F2021&_relator=1&_auditor=1&_materia=1&tipoDocumento=2&_tipoDocumento=1&acao=Executa&offset=0`.